# preg_replace get each two characters from a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Actually I'm trying to come up with a way of getting a string like "GEWO" out of the "Get Word" by using preg_replace function. The thing is there also can be a strings like "Get", or "Get Word And another Word" so I have to get the proper string respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the _"proper string respectively"_?

Comment: so "Get" becomes "GE" and "Get Word and another Word" is "GEWOANANWO"

Comment: You mean you want to break a string down into words, get the first two characters from each word (what happens if the string contains 1-letter words like `A` or `I`) and capitalise those letters.... which bit are you having difficulty with?

Comment: There are no words which contain only 1 character, so I just need to break  a string down based on the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$s = "Get Word And another Word";
$s = preg_replace('/(?<=\w{2})\w*\b(\s|$)/','',$s);
$s = strtoupper($s);
echo $s;
```

ouput: `GEWOANANWO`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without using REGEX, Something like this:

```
$str = 'Get Word';
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($arr as $word){
    $newstr .= strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 2));
}
echo $newstr;
//=> GEWO
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZLBVt)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for lookarounds in the regex pattern.

I'll use `\w` as the regex metacharacter to represent characters in your words. `\w` means any letter, number, or underscore.  You can swap this with `\S` to match any non-whitespace if you wish.  Match the first two word characters, then "forget them" with `\K` (this "restarts the full string match"), then match zero or more word characters (to consume the rest of the word), then match zero or more non-word characters (to match the space or other delimiting characters that come before the next potential word).  Replace these matches with an empty string

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L8hot))

```
echo strtoupper(
         preg_replace(
             '~\w{2}\K\w*\W*~',
             '',
             $string
         )
     );
```

`Extract items through isolation wanting your utility`

becomes

`EXITTHISWAYOUT`

and

`Cannot remember better arguments!`

`CAREBEAR`

There are many fringe scenarios such as single letter words, but I won't go down rabbit holes unnecessarily.